# How to paste into RStudio data on the clipboard

Tags: r, rstudio, clipboard

This is my regular "trick":

`data=read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE, sep=" ")`

However, if I try to copy and paste the following:

```
       Per     Weight
cat 1  0.9753  0.1653   
cat 2  0.9896  0.1891
cat 3  0.9911  0.1673
cat 4  0.9816  0.1667
cat 5  0.9926  0.1748
cat 6  0.9786  0.1367
```

using the line of code above, I get several error messages:

`more columns than column names` - very self explanatory...

or...

`Error: unexpected numeric constant in "1  0.9753"`

So, should I address all these error messages, or is there a way to just import the data, and then deal with inconsistencies from within RStudio?

Comment: Get rid of the first row and also escape the category names, e.g. `'cat 1'`

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to skip the `cat` column when copying by highlighting...

Comment: Can you tell us whence is the source of your data?

Comment: Absolutely. Here... I was trying to "play" with [this question on CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/198608/67822).

Comment: I usually use `read.table(textConnection(' *paste here* '))`. If you do it without the labels, you'll just need to `paste` together the first two columns and reinsert the labels. A few lines, but it'll work.

Comment: @alistaire - that's an awesome tip for single column cut'n'paste from things like Excel.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using `read.table` or similar `read.*` functions, there's usually a `text` argument, too, so you can do `read.table(text = ' ... ')`

Comment: The second error message is probably R *not* recognizing the line break after the first line (the one with the two column names), so it is still reading the second line as if it were the first line, which means that it probably uses "cat" as the third column name and get lost when try to use "1" and "0.9753" as names for the following columns.